# This page has an error

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I've created a lightning-datatable and I'm trying to filter records in the lightning-datatable using a custom search box. However, it displays a pop-up with error which says SORRY TO INTERRUPT -> the page has error when I try to filter the records.

Below is the code I've written to filter records in data-table.

```
    handleSearch(event){
            var searchText = event.target.value;
            console.log('searchText : ' ,searchText);
            try{
                    this.dataListTemp  = this.dataListTemp.filter(function (record) {
                        return record.name.includes(searchText)  ||
                               record.title.includes(searchText) ||
                               record.occupation.includes(searchText);
                      });
                }catch(error){
                    console.log('Error : ' ,error);
                }
    }
```

**dataListTemp** is assigned to the data attribute of lightning-datatable and **handleSearch** is called onchange of text in search box.

I used try-catch just to figure out what's causing this error but catch isn't called at all.

What is the issue here?

Comment: Can records have null/undefined values for name, title or occupation?

Comment: Have you tried to simply add a breakpoint in the filter function and to step through the processing using the browser's java script debugger?

Comment: @PhilW yes, there are certain records where title or oppcupation are undefined/null, but in that case shouldn't I get an error in console?